# Error after compile module into project android

Tags: java, android

this error appear after I imported module. some can help me? thanks

Verification error in java.lang.Object com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity.access$super(com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
    08-02 16:14:43.753 1487-1487/com.colgate.alarm I/art: java.lang.Object com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity.access$super(com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]): [0x1CA] couldn't find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportFinishAfterTransition ()V

```
...

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.colgate.alarm, PID: 1487
                                                                 java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity due to bad method java.lang.Object com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity.access$super(com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) (declaration of 'com.colgate.alarm.MainActivity' appears in /data/data/com.colgate.alarm/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex)
                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

after disable instant run i got this new error

Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: disable instant run and try again

Comment: which part? i just put -> compile project (':game') and and errors came

Comment: thanks for answering, I try disable instant run and I got new error (Question edited)

Comment: I solved this by stopping the app and running it again after rebuilding the project.